# Direct limit and amalgamation (Serre's "Trees")

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, limits-colimits

At the very beginning of Serre's *Trees*, it's taken that the groups $G_i$ (indexed over some set $I$, with no additional specifications) are equipped with homomorphisms $f_{ij}:G_i\to G_j$, collected in $F_{ij}$ defined for all $i,j\in I$. From this, he constructs the direct limit $G$ with maps $f_i:G_i\to G$, satisfying $f_j\circ f_{ij}=f_i$ and a universal property. Then, he gives the example $I=[2]$, with the only specifications on the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ being the existence of homomorphisms $f_i:A\to G_i$ for some other group $A$, and claims that $G$ in this setting is the amalgamated product $G_1*_AG_2$.

My question is exactly what implicit information about $F_{12}$ and $F_{21}$ is given in that example. Here is my best guess. Say $G_1$ is generated by (fixed) $S$, and $T\subset A$ has the set bijection $\phi:T\overset{\sim}{\to}S$ where $\phi=f_1|_T$. Then $f_T=f_2\circ\phi^{-1}$, which extends to all of $G_1$, and $F_{12}=\{f_T:T\subset A,f_1|_T:T\overset{\sim}{\to}S\}$. $F_{21}$ arises analogously. I think this is equivalent to the notion of amalgamation that I've seen elsewhere of handling $f_1(x)f_2(x)^{-1}$, but wanted to be certain by phrasing it explicitly in the notation Serre introduces for the direct limit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the set $I$ assumed to be ordered? Directed? Because if all you have is an index set, then what you have is a colimit, not necessarily a direct limit, and it is unclear which pairs of indices $i$ and $j$ give rise to the homomorphisms $f_{ij}$. You aren’t providing all the *explicit* information, which makes it difficult to tell you what *implicit* information is being assumed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have edited the question to round out what Serre specifies in his definition

Comment: My copy is in my office; if you haven’t gotten a response by tomorrow morning (it’s early evening here right now) I’ll take a look at the book. Right now, I’m not clear on what the set-up is.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To clarify the setup, here is a photo of the relevant section of text, from a related math.SE post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSdjz.jpg (the example with the amalgamation is cut off, but I believe I have reproduced it in the post exactly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, just looked at the book. So for each pair of indices $i$ and $j$; we have a family $F_{ij}$ of morphisms. Far be it for me to correct Serre, so let me instead point out that most people would not call this construction a "direct limit", but rather a colimit. "Direct limit" is usually restricted for the case where $I$ is a directed set (partially ordered set in which every finite subset has an upper bound), and where for each $i$ and $j$, if $i\nleq j$ then $F_{ij}$ is empty; if $i\leq j$ then $F_{ij}=\{f_{ij}\}$ is a singleton; $f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{G_i}$; and the morphisms are requied to satisfy $f_{ik} = f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}$ whenever $i\leq j\leq k$.

I don't think you are reporting the example correctly: the index set is not "$[2]$" as you report (by which I suspect you mean $\{1,2\}$). Here is what he says, explicitly:

> *Example.* Take three groups, $A$, $G_1$, and $G_2$, and two homomorphisms, $f_1\colon A\to G_1$ and $f_2\colon A\to G_2$. One says that the corresponding group $G$ obtained by *amalgating $A$ in $G_1$ and $G_2$* by means of $f_1$ and $f_2$, we denote it by $G_1*_A G_2$. One can have $G=\{1\}$ even though $f_1$ and $f_2$ are non-trivial.

So, here your index set has *three* elements: $1$, $2$, and then a silent index used for $A$. I would denote it by $G_0=A$. Then you have $F_{01}=\{f_1\colon A\to G_1\}$; $F_{02}=\{f_2\colon A\to G_2\}$; and $F_{10}=F_{20}=F_{12}=F_{21}=\varnothing$. In other words, you entire system consists of exactly three groups and exactly two maps, and nothing else. Then you take the colimit/direct limit of *this* system, and you get the free product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ amalgamated over $A$.

Note that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not assumed to be embeddings; that's why the amalgamated product could be trivial.

Your $S$ and $T$ are misguided. If $G_1$ were generated by $S$ and you had a bijection from a subset of $A$ onto $S$ with the restriction of a homomorphism, then the homomorphism would be onto.

The "classic" situation is when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are embeddings, so that $A$ can be identified with a "common" subgroup of $G_1$ and $G_2$; in that case, $G_1*_A G_2$ is defined as $G_1*G_2/N$, where $G_1*G_2$ is the free product, and $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G_1*G_2$ containing all elements of the form $f_1(a)f_2(a)^{-1}$; it is then necessary to prove that this results in a group that contains isomorphic copies of $G_1$ and $G_2$, which intersect precisely "at" $A$. In the more general situation here, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not required to be monomorphisms/injective, this is what is usually called a **pushout** of $f_1$ and $f_2$; that is, you have a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A@>f_1>>G_1\\
@Vf_2VV\\
G_2
\end{CD}$$
and then you seek a universal group $G$ and maps $g_1,g_2$ that fits into the diagram as follows:
$$\begin{CD}
A@>f_1>>G_1\\
@Vf_2VV@VVg_1V\\
G_2@>g_2>>G
\end{CD}$$
so that $g_1f_1=g_2f_2$ and satisfies the relevant universal property relative to that condition.

Comment: . . . n i c e .

Comment: Arturo, thank you so much! This completely clears up my confusion – I think the key point that I had not seen was to view $A$ "with" $G_1,G_2$ as part of the system whose colimit was being taken, instead of just an auxiliary object giving additional data.

Comment: Can someone enlighten me about the construction of the general colimit here? It seems like he's starting with the free group on a disjoint union of generating sets. But then we can only quotient the relations he describes for values of $x, y, z$ in the generating sets.

What if my generating set for $G_i$ contains distinct $x, y, z, t$ such that xyz = t in $G_i$? We should have $[x][y][z]=[t]$ in the quotient. But it doesn't seem like we necessarily do.

Comment: @H.Jenkins Who is "he"? I don't think you mean me, yet you are posting this as a comment in my answer...

Comment: Sorry, I meant Serre in the book, talking about the colimit of a general diagram of groups. English translation reads: 
"Existence is easy. One can, for example, define [the colimit] by generators and relations; one takes the generating family to be the disjoint union of those for the $G_i$; as relations, on the one hand the $xyz^{-1}$ where $x, y, z$ belong to the same $G_i$ and $z=xy$ in $G_i$, on the other hand the $xy^{-1}$ where $x\in G_i$, $y\in G_j$ and $y = f(x)$ for at least one $f$ in $F_{ij}$" [set of maps $G_i \to G_j$].

Comment: @H.Jenkins I don't think this should be a comment. If you want to ask about Serre's construction, ask it as a question. Comments are too cramped to hash out what your doubt is. Also, you are addressing the comment to "Nyone", but other than me (because I got notified by this being a comment on my answer) who else do you expect to just happen to look at an almost 2 year pld question, and dig thorugh the comments, and then answer you?